# Does networkActivityIndicatorVisible work in applicationDidBecomeActive?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, sleep

I am trying to call the network indicator and then dismiss it after this code as you can see below but it does not show in the status bar. What am I doing wrong? I thought it was just that the network activity was completing to quickly but even with the sleep it doesn not seem to work.

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

UIImageView *loadingImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
loadingImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading-splash.png"];
loadingImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
[self.window addSubview:loadingImage];


[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: @"http://mysite.tk/in-app/net.test" ]];
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", serverOutput);
sleep(1);
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"internet is working"])
    {
        [SVStatusHUD showWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"connected.png"] status:@"Connected"];


    } else {

        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Unsuccesful" message:@"App Requests has failed connecting to the server. Some or all of App Requests functions may not work. Please check your internet connection."
                                                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertsuccess show];
        [alertsuccess release];

            }

[loadingImage release]; 
}
```

Also if anyone wants to be kind enough to tell me how to dismiss the image view as well feel free, but I was about to google that. Im a noob trying to learn from tutorials and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show and hide the indicator in a separate thread using something like this.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Put any code you want to execute in the main thread here.
});
```